# Checking form values with re-usable function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I need some help writing a re-usable function for form checking. I want to call the function on an element of my form and perform a value validation; however I am not sure I have written the function correctly to accept the targeted element.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/eKeLt/24/) where you can find all the code.

My questions:

- By using the `element` object as a parameter of the function, does this get the specified element when the user types in values in that input element?
- And can I write the function in this way and then pass it into `addEventListener`?

I am trying to adapt the simple function found at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

The piece of JS code I am trying to get to work is as follows:

```
var A = {

   invoiced: document.getElementById("invoiced"),

   checkValue: function (event, elem) {
       if(elem.validity.typeMismatch)
          elem.setCustomValidity("Only number(s) and '+' and '-' signs");
       else
          elem.setCustomValidity("");
   }
};

A.invoiced.addEventListener("keyup", A.checkValue, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkValue: function(event) {
    var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
...
```

Comment: It would help readers if you add some text explaining why this is the answer.

Comment: The function is still not working as intended. The message displayed when the user clicks `submit` is still the default message of the API, and not the custom message as intended.